# The following produced an error: `$$(x_1, x_d)$$`

Tags: math-mode

Compiling the following document in TeX Live 2023, I obtained the error `Missing $ inserted`:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
    $$(x_1, x_d)$$
\end{document}
```

Question: Is this a bug or is there something about LaTeX that I have missed?

Please note that it works with single-dollar delimiters.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No bug, as it's documented behavior.

1. You should never use `$$` in a LaTeX document.
2. By default, `standalone` basically does `\mbox{<contents>}` and display math is not allowed inside `\mbox`.
3. Just do `$\displaystyle<formula>$`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}

$\displaystyle (x_1, x_d)$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or use `\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}` (that will produce a full "line", whatever it means).

Comment: @Rmano Not with a math display: try it.

Comment: `\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\[ (x_1, x_d) \]
\end{document}` does not error and produces a (horrible) output... 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEynT.png

Comment: @Rmano Indeed! I was referring to the awful output, not to the fact that it compiles.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Your point 2 is new to me, thanks for the information. I knew about point 1, but `$$...$$` is just too practical for me so I could never give up on it. Especially because I'm using the French keyboard layout, typing `\` needs a combination of three keys, same for `[`, thus a total of 6 key presses just for `\[`, too much!!!